# Load CSV MySQLdb - Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a CSV that I'm attempting to load into a MySQL database. I'm running the following code:

```
import MySQLdb

con = MySQLdb.connect(host="myhost",
                          user="me", 
                          passwd="mypw",
                          db="mydb")


cur = con.cursor()

sqlscript =r"""
DROP TABLE  IF EXISTS MyTable;

CREATE TABLE MyTable
            (Col1 VARCHAR(255), 
            Col2 VARCHAR(255), 
            CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable PRIMARY KEY (Col1));

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\Rec\\New Files\\mycsv.csv'
INTO TABLE MyTable
CHARACTER SET UTF8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ESCAPED BY '!'
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;"""

cur.execute(sqlscript)
cur.close()
```

This runs without error, but does not load data from my CSV file. It correctly drops the table and creates it using the script. When I then query the table, it has zero rows. What am I missing?

Comment: You forgot to commit

Comment: that was it, thanks for the help